# Repeat tabs using TabLayoutMediator

Tags: android-fragments, android-viewpager2, tablayout

How should we repeat a tabs after finish the last tab again first onward start. Like a cycle.
Ex:1, 2,3 and again 1,2,3
And selected tab always center only.

And need to show fragments for each tab .
With supporting Viewpager2.

Can any one please help me how to achieve this.

I need to show fragments using tabs and selected tab always center of the tabs.

Comment: You can look at this [library](https://github.com/cuichanghao/infivt), it seems to do what you need.